# Android back stack issue with detail activity and navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, back-stack

I am having a small problem with android's back stack.

I have the following activity stack:

```
Root -> ActivityA -> Detail
```

The Root Activity has launchMode set `singleTask`, the others are standard.

When switching to another activity using the navigation drawer, I call finish on the current activity (if it's not root) and launch the selected one. This works as long as I have only one level of activites.
However when the drawer is used from the Detail activity, the back stack still contains ActivityA (as expected so far, because only the detail activity is finished).

```
Root -> ActivityA -> ActivityB
```

I always want to have the root and the selected activity after using the drawer

```
Root -> ActivityX
```

I already tried adding the flags `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` when starting a new task from the navigation drawer, but that results in the Root Activity being finished too and pressing back in ActivityB will close the whole app and not go back to the root.

Edit:
A good example for what I want is the gmail app: select a label (my ActivtyA) and open a mail from it (my Detail). Then use the drawer to go to a different label (my ActivityB). Pressing the back key will bring it back to the default inbox (my root).

Comment: Have you tried to start the activities with the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY flag?

Comment: This is not an option because I want to have the history (pressing back in detail should go back to activityA, pressing back again to root)

Comment: I guess you have Base activity class. Just override OnBackPressed in your base activity to create intent and return to your root activity with Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Comment: Maybe using fragments inside ActivityA, ActivityB gives you what you want. Or calling finish on current activity and its ancestors, unless Root, of course